# python prompt_toolkit ImportError

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, importerror, circular-reference, prompt-toolkit

I've created a simple script to begin building a python prompt with `prompt_toolkit` but am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'PromptSession' from partially initialized module 'prompt_toolkit' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/coreyfarmer/Coding/Testing/prompt_toolkit.py)
```

I'm running `python3.8.7` in a virtualenv, but seem to be running into the issue outside of the virtualenv and with varying versions of python as well.  I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling varying versions of `prompt_toolkit` with the same results.

The script is simple and is based off samples/examples on the [prompt_toolkit docs](https://python-prompt-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/master/pages/asking_for_input.html):

```
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession

def start ( ) :
    session = PromptSession()

    text1 = session.prompt("Give me some input: ")
    print( "You said: %s" % text1 )

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    start ()
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve would be very welcome.

**UPDATE**

After changing the filename from `prompt_toolkit.py` (which was conflicting with the package name) to `my_prompt_toolkit.py` I get the following error:

```
~/Coding via  v3.8.7 (env)
❯ python3 Testing/my_prompt_toolkit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Testing/my_prompt_toolkit.py", line 1, in <module>
    from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
ImportError: cannot import name 'PromptSession' from 'prompt_toolkit'
  (/Users/coreyfarmer/Coding/valet.com/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prompt_toolkit/__init__.py)
```

Which is strange because I know the package exists and is in the right place:

```
~/Coding via  v3.8.7 (env)
❯ python3 -m pip show prompt_toolkit
Name: prompt-toolkit
Version: 1.0.18
Summary: Library for building powerful interactive command lines in Python
Home-page: https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit
Author: Jonathan Slenders
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /Users/coreyfarmer/Coding/valet.com/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: six, wcwidth
Required-by:
```

Comment: Is your file named _prompt_tookit.py_? If so, can you try to rename it and try again?

Comment: enzo is correct. You've shadowed the `prompt_toolkit` package with a file named `/Users/coreyfarmer/Coding/Testing/prompt_toolkit.py`.

Comment: thanks guys, definitely shouldn't have done that.  After changing the name and updating the `prompt_toolkit` package to the most recent again everything is working